# Book about children having dream adventures in aunt & uncle's house

Tags: story-identification

Trying to identify a children's/middle grade book I read in the early 2000's.  It's about a brother and sister staying at their aunt & uncle's house.  When they fall asleep, they go on adventures in their dreams, a different one each night:

- they get caught in bubbles and have to escape (the bubbles get harder and harder to pop)
- the girl finds herself standing before two future versions of herself (a mean one and a kind one) and has to pick which one she wants
- they shrink so they fit into a house made of blocks, which falls on them
- an evil snowman chases them
- etc

I think one of them gets trapped in a dream for a while.

Also, the uncle secretly sends the girl a Valentine's card and she's disappointed when she finds out she doesn't really have a secret admirer.

There's a villain, a man who I think is the aunt's old beau, controlling the dreams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Diamond In The Window  by Jane Langton](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/jane-langton/diamond-window/)

> An old New England house about to be usurped by creditors, is the setting. Tracing valuable treasure to save it,- the problem. The solid citizens of Concord have threatened Aunt Lily with eviction unless she can scrape up the back taxes on her house. Determined to help, Eddy and Eleanor begin rummaging through the attic and discover a hidden room where two children lived years ago. According to Aunt Lily, Ned and Nora disappeared from their beds along with her fiance, Prince Krishna. As Eddy and Eleanor settle down in the mysterious beds, **they are thrown headlong into a series of dual dreams** —exciting and colorful — each inspired by Uncle Freddy's quotations from Thorean and Emerson or by a possible clue to the hidden treasure. **The bubble dream** climaxes a long odyssey.